# What is the difference between "exalt" and "extol"?

Tags: differences

I get very similar result when I translate it to my native language.

Comment: "Exalt" carries a sense of "raising" the subject of the praise to a high level, as one might do with royalty or deity.  "Extol" means "praise", but it's "normal" praise, not (so much) with regal or religious connotations.  (And both tend to be used mainly in idioms, vs normal conversation/text.)

Comment: To agree with @HotLicks - If you extol, it means you are taking the trouble to list positive attributes that are already true.  If you exalt, it means that your words or actions increase the status of the one being exalted. You exalt a person, but you extol a person's attributes.  For example, you may extol her virtue, her prowess, or her talent.

Comment: Please quote for us the dictionaries you have checked so that we can understand why you are still confused.

Comment: It is very unfortunate the question was closed for the reason of lacking research, because this question is the *only* relevant hit that Google shows.

Answer (score 3):

Per the *OED* *exalt* (from the Latin *ex-* + *altus*, high) means to raise or lift.  Usages in the physical sense are considered archaic, and the word is now used figuratively of "rank, honor, estimation, power, or wealth."  As an example, the *OED* uses Erskine May's *The Constitutional History of England*:

> [George III] came to the throne determined to *exalt* the kingly office.

In the sense of "dignify or ennoble," the *OED* turns to Ralph Waldo Emerson (in *Nature*):

> The moment our discourse rises above the ground line of familiar facts, and is inflamed with passion or **exalted** by thought, it clothes itself in images.

In the sense to stimulate to a higher level:  "exalting the imagination" (George Eliot, *Mill on the Floss*)

But *exalt* is also a synonym for *extol* meaning to praise, and the *OED* sees fit to quote Thomas Hood's *Tale of a Trumpet* about the unfortunate deaf Mrs S. and her attempts to restore her hearing:

> But all remedies fail'd; and though
>        some it was clear
>        (Like the brandy and salt
>        We now **exalt**)
>  Had made a noise
>   in the public ear,
>  She was just as deaf as ever, poor dear.

*Extol* (from the Latin *ex-* + *tollere*, to raise) had the same meanings as *exalt*, but the senses of lifting up other than to praise highly are now obsolete.